# How to make p:selectOneMenu show current value?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `<p:selectOneMenu>` to choose the category for an item from. By default the menu displays the first entry of `someBean.selectedParty.categories` as selected. But the item already has a current category at `someBean.selectedItem.category` that I want to be displayed/selected. How can I achieve that?

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{someBean.selectedItem.category}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{someBean.selectedParty.categories}" var="category" itemLabel="#{category.name}"/>   
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Do you mean that on page load, `someBean.selectedItem.category` has a default value? Or after a selection, the current value is not updated?

Comment: The first one is correct: The Item is selected before, all it's other attributes can be displayed. But for category I want to display the current value inside a dropdown menu that holds all available categories and enables the user to change the category to another than the current.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds blunt, but I have really no utter idea what problem you're concretely struggling with. The code given so far should definitely show the `#{someBean.selectedItem.category}` as currently selected item if it's been preset. An SSCCE along with an use case may be helpful in understanding your concrete problem.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for pushing me to the solution. While creating the SSCCE it occurred to me that in my setup I had to override hashCode() and equals() again, because otherwise the selected category and it's counterpart in the list to select from would not be recognized as same due to different hashcodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the getter for someBean.selectedItem.category returns a value available in the list , it will show the value as selected.

However there are some gotchas:
1) The default value probably should be set in the bean constructor

2) The bean (someBean) cannot have the RequestScope - As every single HTTP request, including Ajax requests, would create a completely brand new instance of the bean with all properties set to default. If your bean is RequestScope, change to ViewScope

3) As you are "cascading" from someBean to selectedItem to category, note that the selectedItem and selectedParty must be the same through (not only same content but also same memory adress) or the lifecycle of JSF will stop. I guess you are setting the selected objects earlier. If you are using AJAX, try to post a "full" request to a new page with the drop-down to debug this.

4) To simplify this, you could try to move the category and categories directly into someBean so the page should look like

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{someBean.category}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{someBean.categories}" var="category" itemLabel="#category.name}"/>    
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise till I created a SSCCE like BalusC proposed in his comment on my question, but I guess point 3 in your list quite describes the problem I encountered (also see my 2nd comment on my question).